# Is there an inequality such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}\leq \frac{1}{n}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k})(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{k})$?

Tags: inequality

Is there an inequality such that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}\leq \frac{1}{n}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k})(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{k})$$

with some restrictions on $a_{k}$ and $b_{k}$?

Comment: [Chebyshev's sum inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality)

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$